# WSL no external connection (internet)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After some time, my wsl (version 2) ubuntu instance stopped being able to connect to the internet (or my lan). After trying some stuff uninstalling vswitches and wsl version and what not, I'm now with an ubuntu 22.04 instance installed from microsoft store.

```
C:\Users\User>wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-22.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

Here is some samples from the ubuntu instance:

```
user@user-pc:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1051ms

user@user-pc:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:34:7d:c9:f8:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9e:b3:a3:0d:f0:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:8b:f1:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.56.58/20 brd 172.21.63.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe8b:f143/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
user@user-pc:~$
user@user-pc:~$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56667
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             0       IN      A       142.250.185.238

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 172.21.48.1#53(172.21.48.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed May 11 22:55:02 EEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54


#############################################################
### My LAN is 10.0.1.0/24 and physical host is 10.0.1.120 ###
#############################################################

user@user-pc:~$ ping 10.0.1.120
PING 10.0.1.120 (10.0.1.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.1.120: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.198 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.120: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.225 ms
^C
--- 10.0.1.120 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1039ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.198/0.211/0.225/0.013 ms
user@user-pc:~$
```

So I have DNS resolution and access to wsl host but no internet (nor other devices in my LAN)

Here are some host networking stuff

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet 2                Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Cli...      17 Disabled     00-05-9A-3C-7A-00       995 Mbps
Ethernet                  Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connec...      15 Up           24-4B-FE-9A-2A-4F         1 Gbps
Local Area Connection     Xbox Wireless Adapter for Windows            14 Up           62-45-B5-04-86-A6       600 Mbps
vEthernet (WSL)           Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2          36 Up           00-15-5D-B0-3C-B7        10 Gbps
vEthernet (Default Swi... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             30 Up           00-15-5D-4A-07-41        10 Gbps

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPConfiguration


InterfaceAlias       : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex       : 15
InterfaceDescription : Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
NetProfile.Name      : Network
IPv4Address          : 10.0.1.120
IPv6DefaultGateway   : fe80::9
IPv4DefaultGateway   : 10.0.1.1
DNSServer            : 10.0.1.1

InterfaceAlias       : vEthernet (Default Switch)
InterfaceIndex       : 30
InterfaceDescription : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
IPv4Address          : 172.17.32.1
IPv6DefaultGateway   :
IPv4DefaultGateway   :
DNSServer            : fec0:0:0:ffff::1
                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2
                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3

InterfaceAlias       : vEthernet (WSL)
InterfaceIndex       : 36
InterfaceDescription : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
IPv4Address          : 172.21.48.1
IPv6DefaultGateway   :
IPv4DefaultGateway   :
DNSServer            : fec0:0:0:ffff::1
                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2
                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3

PS C:\Users\User> Get-NetNat
PS C:\Users\User>
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are on a corporate network with admin access but a tricky firewall.

## In Powershell

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow

Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public -DisabledInterfaceAliases "vEthernet (WSL)"

Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Private -DisabledInterfaceAliases "vEthernet (WSL)"